# Zoom in out of Words css

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, zooming

[image]

I'm trying to do a WordCloud with zoom in-out of words. I'm using JavaScript to randomly set CSS to zoom the words, however the words just disappear and then appear.

This is my ***CSS*** code:

```
svg text.zoom {
   /* Webkit for Chrome and Safari */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1); /*This is the scale for the normal size of the image. */
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;

  /* Webkit for Mozila Firefox */
  -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: ease-in-out;


  /* Webkit for IE( Version: 11, 10 ) */
  -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Please verify your CSS selector, your code should work clearly if you change to a different scale, if you can share the full code, that would be great.

Comment: The thing that is happening now is that he is chaging the words to the top of the wordcloud and it wasn't showing on the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have missed the standart transition property. Try adding the following **CSS** code

```
svg text.zoom{
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

I hope this will help

Comment: @Ana Brandão If this helped, you can mark it as answer by clicking the tick (√)  under the voting ;)

Comment: @Ana, I've suggested edit of your question, and while editing, I've noticed your coment for the scale set as **//Comment** instead of **/* Comment */**. Please check your code ;)